# Postgresql query from console

Tags: regex, postgresql, console

I have something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column=REGEXP_REPLACE(column, E'\[(.*)\]$', '');
```

Everything is ok with this query, but the problem exists when I want to do this from console, like here:

```
psql -U postgres db -c "UPDATE table SET column=REGEXP_REPLACE(column, E'\\[(.*)\\]$', '');"
```

I think there is a problem with escaping some characters, but I cannot handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a Unix-like shell, as an alternative to passing the query with `-c` and complicated multi-level quoting, it could be passed in its original form in the standard input using [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) syntax:

```
$ psql db << EOF
UPDATE table SET column=REGEXP_REPLACE(column, E'\[(.*)\]$', '');
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the correct way is:

```
UPDATE table SET column=REGEXP_REPLACE(column, E'\\\[(.*)\\\]$', '');
```

I tried with escaping a $ sign, but this didn't help at all. I understand that one "\" is for bash to escape another one which is needed to db to escape next one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem came from the `$`. Try with :

```
postgres db -c "UPDATE table SET column=REGEXP_REPLACE(column, E'\\[(.*)\\]\$', '');"
```

A parameter passed within double quote is evaluated. That's mean it's recognize bash special caracters, like the `$`, but a parameter within simple quote is not.